# Extracting person and domain from BigQuery table and creating a new one

Tags: google-bigquery

**Hi everyone!** I'm VERY new to BigQuery on GCP.
I'm trying to extract from a table I have about the Israeli news data the name of the person that is most mentioned from a specific domain (which is an Israeli news site) and create a new table with the name of the person and the name of the domain.

**This was my code:**

```
1. SELECT
2.  domain,
3.  person,
4. FROM
5.  `project.dataset.MyNewsTable` 
6. SELECT
7.  person,
8. SUM(count_of_mentions) AS all_mentions
9. FROM
10.  `project.dataset.MyNewsTable`
11. WHERE
12.  domain = 'walla.co.il'
```

**The error that came up is: syntax error:** Expected end of input but got keyword SELECT at [5:1]

but I don't understand what it means and what should I change.
Hopefully I wrote everything in a way you can understand, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to execute two queries at the same time in BQ, please put the semicolon at the end of line 5.

Answer (score 0):

You seem new to SQL in general, not BigQuery in Particular.

You are trying to run 2 queries at the same time. You should run them one by one.

```
SELECT
  domain,
  person,
 FROM
  `project.dataset.MyNewsTable`;
```

```
SELECT
 person,
SUM(count_of_mentions) AS all_mentions
FROM
  `project.dataset.MyNewsTable`
 WHERE
  domain = 'walla.co.il';
```